# Check for trigger entry point in axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two gameObjects which are having triggers. I am able to detect if a gameObject is coming in contact with another using OnTriggerEnter(). Now I would like to know from which axis it has been entered. I just want to detect the point of entry for the collision. How do I achieve this?

```
    public int error_x = 0;

    void Start () { }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
        if (!enabled) return;
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube01") {
            error_x++; //only if the entry point is in x axis
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider col) {
        if (!enabled) return;
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube01" ) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why you need axis? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the x position of your collider is greater than the triggers x position:

```
if(col.transform.position.x > transform.position.x){
    //The collider touched from the x axis
}
```